# Upload Different file types using OKHTTP3

Tags: android, okhttp

My objective is to upload different media types using okhttp3, so far the below method can upload images and it can also upload videos. However I want to be able to upload .mp3,.mp4 and jpg files. What MediaType supports all three in okhttp3

```
    final MediaType MEDIA_TYPE_PNG = MediaType.parse("image/jpg");

    MultipartBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
            .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
            .addFormDataPart("attachment",path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/")+1)
                    ,RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_PNG, new File(path)))
            .addFormDataPart("token",token)
            .addFormDataPart("user_id",user_id)
            .addFormDataPart("title",ptitle)
            .addFormDataPart("id",preportid)
            .addFormDataPart("object_type", optype)
            .addFormDataPart("key", getAPIKey(ctx))
            .addFormDataPart("content", "(empty)")
            .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

following this tutorial https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-upload-files-to-server you can upload any file